# Can these nested 'if typeof(bla) else' statements be done shorter?

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code that goes like this. This piece of code works but it looks horrible.

```
if(typeof(d.object) != "undefined"){
  if(typeof(d.object.property) != "undefined"){
    if(typeof(d.object.property.length) != "undefined"){
      // do the code
    }
    else alert("error");
  }
  else alert("error");
}
else alert("error");
```

Is there any way this can be rewritten so it does the same but more efficient. Especially because the errors are all the same.

Comment: `typeof` and comparisong with `undefined` isn't required here. Just use `if (d.object && d.object.property ...)`

Comment: @zerkms The final value could be falsy without being undefined.

Comment: @Asad: for `d.object` and `d.object.property` it doesn't matter

Comment: @zerkms Yeah true, I just meant for the final `length`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supposing you're not interested in the `property` if its length is null or `0` (or more generally "falsy" as suggested by Jan Dvorak), then you might make it a little more readable even without using `try/catch` :

```
if (d && d.object && d.object.property && d.object.property.length){

} else {
   alert('error');
}
```

in most cases this is the way to go.

About the "falsy", [from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) :

> Any value that is not undefined, null, 0, NaN, or the empty string
>   (""), and any object, including a Boolean object whose value is false,
>   evaluates to true when passed to a conditional statement

Comment: note that neither `0` nor `false` have the properties `object`, `property` or `length`.

Comment: of course, then there's the empty string that does have a length and is falsy as well.

Comment: I suggest "if it's falsy".

Comment: This doesn't behave identically to the original code. Consider this example. http://jsfiddle.net/nL9nZ/1/

Comment: @Asad yes but it's most probably an improvement. And that's why I precised "Supposing you're not interested in the property's length if it's null or 0"

Answer (score 2):

```
try{
    if(typeof(d.object.property.length) != "undefined"){
      // do the code
    }else{
      throw "Value undefined";
    }
}catch(e){
    alert("error");
}
```

This works as long as you're just refactoring some code that you know works, but it makes debugging harder.

Answer (score 0):

Good suggestions,

this is a job for a function!

```
function has(v){return typeof(v) !== "undefined";};

if(has(d) && has(d.object) && has(d.object.property) && has(d.object.property.lenth)) {
   ...
} else alert("error");
```

Regards